# Convert Word DOCX files to Template DOTX files without opening each one

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

I have a load of forms in Word DOCX format that I want to convert to templates. In the olden days I could rename a .DOC to a .DOT and this would be sufficient to change the file into a template, but this doesn't work for the new .DOCX -> .DOTX formats.

I know I can open each file and re-save it as .DOTX but I don't want to have to manually re-save every file.

What is the easiest way to "convert" a DOCX to a DOTX template?

Comment: See StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51252040/i-want-to-convert-docx-to-dotx .There are also online services, such as https://products.groupdocs.app/conversion/docx-to-dotx and https://www.converter365.com/document-converter/dotx/dotx-to-docx, though I have no experience with them. If you have PII in the documents, such as author or company name, you might not want to use an online service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a time that document files and template files were identical
except for the file extension, but this is no longer the case.
Today this requires either using a dedicated product, an online converter
or writing your own.

Here are some (untested) scripts. They require all the `.docx` files to be inside one folder, and they ultimately use Word for the conversion.

From the article
[Converting Word document format with PowerShell](https://steveknutson.blog/2021/06/09/converting-word-document-format-with-powershell/)
I have adapted this PowerShell script, with help from
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55399509/165358):

```
$wdTypes = Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word' -Passthru
$wdSaveFormat = $wdTypes | Where {$_.Name -eq "wdSaveFormat"}

$path = "c:\path-to-files\" 
$word_app = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

$Format = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatXMLTemplate

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.docx | ForEach-Object {
    $document = $word_app.Documents.Open($_.FullName)
    $dotx_filename = "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.BaseName).dotx"
    $document.SaveAs([ref] $dotx_filename, [ref]$Format)
    $document.Close()
}
$word_app.Quit()
```

In the post
[Quickly convert .docx files in a folder to .dotx format](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5a8ac042-ff4c-44c2-bd94-32f9a58d003f/quickly-convert-docx-files-in-a-folder-to-dotx-format?forum=word)
I have found this VBA macro:

```
Sub DOCX_To_DOTX()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document
strFolder = GetFolder
If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  wdDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=strFolder & "\" & Split(strFile, ".docx")(0) & ".dotx", Fileformat:=wdFormatXMLTemplate, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  wdDoc.Close
  'Kill strFolder & "\" & strFile
  DoEvents
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
 
Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

I have done no testing of the above scripts, so I suggest letting them
work on a copy of the folder containing the `.docx` files and not
on the originals.

Comment: Thanks for this, the PS script looks to be the best solution. I have an issue with the format line though $Format = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatXMLTe …
     |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to find type [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat].
InvalidOperation:

Comment: Ah, fixed by using the lines from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53170039/powershell-unable-to-find-type-microsoft-office-interop-word-wdsaveformat

Comment: I added these lines into my answer.